# My CSS replaces the text outside of the button

Tags: html, css, button, text

I'm making a simple match the card game and i styled the buttons a bit to make the more appealing but the style code make it to the text is outside of the button and if I move the text the button moves with it if any one would be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong here please do.

Complete HTML code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>cardgame</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="result">2</h1>

<form class="cards">
    <div id="cards1"></div>
    <input id="cards1[1]" value="1" name="card1" type="radio">
    <label for="cards1[1]">1</label>
    <input id="cards1[2]" value="2" name="card1" type="radio">
    <label for="cards1[2]">2</label>
    <input id="cards1[3]" value="3" name="card1" type="radio">
    <label for="cards1[3]">3</label>
    </div>
    <div id="cards2">
        <input id="cards2[1]" value="1" name="card2" type="radio"><label for="cards2[1]"> </label>
        <input id="cards2[2]" value="2" name="card2" type="radio"><label for="cards2[2]"> </label>
        <input id="cards2[3]" value="3" name="card2" type="radio"><label for="cards2[3]"> </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>



<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Complete CSS code

```
    .credit {
    background: lightyellow;
}

body {background-color: floralwhite}


label {
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
    top: -3px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    opacity: .5;
}


input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 6px 6px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your text inside a span and then try to move it. Example:

```
<div id="cards1">
 <input id="cards1[1]" value="1" name="card1" type="radio">
 <label for="cards1[1]"><span class="text">1</span></label>
 <input id="cards1[2]" value="2" name="card1" type="radio">
 <label for="cards1[2]"><span class="text">2</span></label>
 <input id="cards1[3]" value="3" name="card1" type="radio">
 <label for="cards1[3]"><span class="text">3</span></label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 8pt;
  opacity: .5;
  position:relative;
  left:-35px;
}
```

Comment: this fixed my code thanks a lot.
I've also learned about the <span> tag so that's a bonus

Answer (score 0):

To solve it you should change the type of your inputs to buttons, and then change your css to work with buttons, and surround the button with a div for the card, here I have solved the problem

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>cardgame</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="result">2</h1>

<form class="cards">
    <div id="cards1">
        <div class="card">
            <input id="cards1[1]" value="1" name="card1" type="button">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <input id="cards1[2]" value="2" name="card1" type="button">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <input id="cards1[3]" value="3" name="card1" type="button">           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cards2">
        <input id="cards2[1]" value="1" name="card2" type="button"><label for="cards2[1]"> </label>
        <input id="cards2[2]" value="2" name="card2" type="button"><label for="cards2[2]"> </label>
        <input id="cards2[3]" value="3" name="card2" type="button"><label for="cards2[3]"> </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>



<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**And the CSS is:**

```
.credit {
    background: lightyellow;
}

body {background-color: floralwhite}

label {
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
    top: -3px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    opacity: .5;
    text-align: center
}


input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="button"] {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 6px 6px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
```